# What is the likely ethnic origin of the Minoans?

Tags: ancient-history, greece, mediterranean

Ever since the discovering and unearthing of the Knossos Palace in Northern Crete over 100 years ago, Archaeology and History have learned a great deal about "The Minoans"-(or Ancient Cretans).  However, we are still unsure as to what their ethnicity was. The Linear A tablets are still a cryptic challenge for the most advanced Linguists and we are still unsure as to the ethnic origins of the Ancient Cretans.  Could the Ancient Cretans have been a distant Pre-Mycenaean Greek civilization, a greater Egyptian civilization who ventured beyond the Nile Valley or perhaps a civilization and people who were lost to history due to the massive Tsunami which destroyed up to 80% of the island's native population 3600 years ago?

Comment: Per your question: "we are still unsure as to what their ethnicity was".

Comment: Maybe difficult to answer, but still a legitimate question.

Comment: We can be pretty sure they weren't Egyptian, because then Linear A would have been done in Egyptian Hieroglyphs.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I should mention that I have seen, "The Wall" many times over the years and (without sounding too cliched), I am big fan of "The Dark Side of the Moon" & "Meddle".

Comment: I brought up the possibility of Egypt, due to the fact when looking at photos of the Linear A tablets-(I have not been to the Museums in Heraklion or Athens, Greece to examine the tablets up close), they appear to have a quasi-hieroglyphic writing; not necessarily hieroglyphs proper, but a quasi-hieroglyphic appearance. in other words, Minoan Crete MAY have been a semi-distant Egyptian colony whereby a related Egyptian language was cultivated and used. Admittedly, it is a stretch of the historical imagination, though still plausible nevertheless.

Comment: @Spencer: it's a legitimate question, but not one whose answer is known at this time by Alex' own admission. That in itself makes it a bad question, since it's inviting opinion-based speculation that cannot be sourced or verified. It ought to get closed as primarily opinion based because of this.

Comment: This is comment is directed at Mr. De Bernardy.  First, the question is not a "bad question".  If you had examined my posting more closely you will see that it is not "inviting opinion based speculation that cannot be sourced or verified".  Speculation, on historically related matters in particular, is part of the inquiry and epistemological process; without speculation, that is to say, without a theoretical standpoint, one cannot pursue a sound scientific conclusion. Asking about the ethnic origins of the Minoans is a perfectly legitimate question within the context of historical discourse.

Comment: @Alex: as much as I agree with you in principle, on what basis are you assuming that you can ask random strangers on the internet to come up with an answer to a question that, by your own admittance, has been inconclusively debated in relevant esoteric spheres to the point where even specialists on the topic openly admit they've no idea what the answer is? Pending new evidence that would make this question on topic, the only two things you can possibly get as answers are unsourced speculations and conspiracist theories.

Comment: What you have just stated may be true, however, I still believe that such a question is not a "bad question". The origins of Minoan Crete has been a growing archaeological field for over 100 years and asking questions regarding the ethnic composition of the Ancient Cretans is absolutely legitimate and worthwhile.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, totally agree that it is worthwhile to ask. But not while knowing all along that there is no answer. _That_ is what makes your question (IMO) bad. Had you asked the same question without mentioning this, someone might have volunteered "no answer" as an actual answer while grumbling about there being "no prior research". But as things stand, you actually did do preliminary research, so the question is de facto prompting for speculation (and thus ought to be closed as primarily opinion-based) or you're hoping it'll basically stay open, unanswered, for years on end.

Comment: My position remains unchanged.

Comment: Note, he did ask for the likely origins, which is not unreasonable. Didn't they have chariots?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am unsure as to whether or not the Minoans had chariots. They may have had chariots, similar to the Egyptians of their age, however, I don't have an exact answer.

Comment: Yes, a few years ago, I either read an article or saw a Television documentary-(it may have been produced by the BBC), which reported on the likely European origins of the Minoans.  From what I remember from the report, the DNA evidence linked some of the existing Greco-Cretan population with some of the peoples living in contemporary Spain-(though I forgot which region they specified).  Remember when the Tsunami devastated much of Crete, the very few who were able to leave the ravaged island traveled to other lands; and in all likelihood, they traveled to lands West of Crete.

Comment: Perhaps Spain, was the most advantageous to the early Cretans. Again, it is a story that dates back a few years, though it may have some historical and anthropological plausibility.

Answer (score 5):

An [analysis of DNA evidence](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2871), published in Nature back in 2013, suggested that the Minoans were a local European civilisation. A few reports since have refined the details, but the main conclusion still seems to be accepted.

The very [latest published research](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v548/n7666/full/nature23310.html) that I've found (in the latest issue of Nature, dated *today* -  10 August 2017) shows that the Minoans and Mycenaeans were genetically very similar, having at least three-quarters of their ancestry from the earliest Neolithic farmers of western Anatolia and the Aegean.

The main difference between the Mycenaeans and the Minoans seems to be that the Mycenaeans

> "derived additional ancestry from a more distant source related to the hunter–gatherers of eastern Europe and Siberia".